# TYPO3 6.2.7: Exception/CMS/1314516809 how to resolve?

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, fal

One of the client's TYPO3 instance went to 1&1 provider... apparently FAL has problems with case of the filenames, cause when entering **Filelist** module I'm getting this exception:  [Exception/CMS/1314516809](http://wiki.typo3.org/Exception/CMS/1314516809)

I cannot change the case of files, cause for an example they follows the name convention of TYPO3, and/or they belongs to extensions from the TER (so shouldn't/cannot be changed)

How can I resolve this problem at 1&1 host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually as usually in TYPO3 it's not a bug, it's a feature ;)

I updated [Exception/CMS/1314516809](http://wiki.typo3.org/Exception/CMS/1314516809#Check_case_sensitivity_setting_in_.60File_storage.60_record) description, fast test showed that it occasionally also resolves other problems i.e.: missing files and/or records:

> #### Check  case sensitivity setting in File storage record
>
> Most problems rises when you are migrating from case-insensitive to case-sensitive file system, or when auto-generated File Storage didn't recognize case-sensitivity correctly.
>
> In such situation created **File storage** saves file identifiers with lower-case in DB and can't find files which has mixed case.
>
> #### Solution
>
> - Find all **File Storages** via module List on 'page zero' and on tab **Configuration** check the
>     **Uses case sensitive identifiers** checkbox.